# JavaScript: Removing decorators from create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Firstly, I want to say that I am very new to react world. I am using a react component from github in our project. I noticed that the component uses `decorators` in their code. And, to use that code as it is, I think we have to `eject` and use `babel`. But, we don't want to do that, so I plan to remove decorators (multiple) with the native code.

```
import React from 'react'
import dc from 'dc'
import BaseChart from './base-chart'
import coordinateGridMixin from '../mixins/coordinate-grid-mixin'
import stackMixin from '../mixins/stack-mixin'
import barMixin from '../mixins/bar-mixin'

@barMixin
@stackMixin
@coordinateGridMixin
export default class BarChart extends BaseChart{
  static displayName = 'BarChart'

  componentDidMount(){
    this.chart = dc.barChart(this.chart)
    this.configure()
    this.chart.render()
  }
}
```

I started this with the following code, with the help of this [page](https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-mobx-decorators/).

```
import React from 'react'
import dc from 'dc'
import BaseChart from './base-chart'
import coordinateGridMixin from '../mixins/coordinate-grid-mixin'
import stackMixin from '../mixins/stack-mixin'
import barMixin from '../mixins/bar-mixin'
import compose from 'recompose'

class BarChart extends BaseChart {
  static displayName = 'BarChart'

  componentDidMount(){
    this.chart = dc.barChart(this.chart)
    this.configure()
    this.chart.render()
  }
}

export default compose(
  coordinateGridMixin,
  stackMixin,
  barMixin
)(BarChart);
```

Doing this I get an error `"export 'default' (imported as 'compose') was not found in 'recompose'`

That make me wonder, do I need to use `recompose`? Or, there is a different and simpler way? Not sure how to replace this piece.

```
export default ???(
  coordinateGridMixin,
  stackMixin,
  barMixin
)(BarChart);
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure if I have given enough information to you to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is about `recompose` exporting nothing by default, so your import is incorrect, you should import `compose` like this :

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
```

You can also chain decorate your component to do it without `recompose` (not 100% sure about the syntax) :

```
let decoratedBarChart = coordinateGridMixin(BarChart);
decoratedBarChart = stackMixin(decoratedBarChart);
decoratedBarChart = barMixin(decoratedBarChart);
export default decoratedBarChart;
```